# Пересборка Sqlite3 для поддержки кириллицы

Tags: c++, sqlite

Мне нужна поддержка кириллицы в SQL функции LOWER. Система Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Сейчас работает неверно:

```
select lower("СТЕК");
СТЕК
```

Я нашел [решение](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=ext/icu&ci=trunk) на официальном сайте, его суть:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared icu.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags icu-uc icu-io` -o libSqliteIcu.so
```

Файл `icu.c` скачивается там же.

Но при сборке возникает ошибка:

```
icu.c: In function ‘sqlite3IcuInit’:
icu.c:510:41: error: ‘SQLITE_DIRECTONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SQLITE_READONLY’?
     {"icu_load_collation",2,SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_DIRECTONLY,1, icuLoadCollation},
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                         SQLITE_READONLY
icu.c:510:41: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
icu.c:502:53: error: ‘SQLITE_INNOCUOUS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SQLITE_NOLFS’?
 # define SQLITEICU_EXTRAFLAGS (SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS)
                                                     ^
icu.c:512:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘SQLITEICU_EXTRAFLAGS’
     {"regexp", 2, SQLITE_ANY|SQLITEICU_EXTRAFLAGS,         0, icuRegexpFunc},
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`pkg-config --libs --cflags icu-uc icu-io` выдает `-licuio -licui18n -licuuc -licudata`.

Как правильно собрать эту библиотеку?

Comment: Попробуйте второй способ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578661

Comment: проще ИМХО было бы действительно весь sqlite с поддержкой icu пересобрать (`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU` в `CFLAGS`)... но если нужен именно модуль под конкретно ту версию, что есть в системе, то нужно взять модуль той же версии, что и системная библиотека... на бубунте, если сорцовые репы подключены, то можно просто получить её через `apt-get source sqlite`.